# Bootstrap Carousel to play mp4 with ajax

Tags: ajax, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, video-streaming, carousel

I'd like to stream and play videos from my django site, I've already converted them to mp4 and was thinking about using the carousel widget with bootstrap to play them. Of course I would like to only load the current video and lazy load the rest, as there could be serveral.

I've been scouring the net to find good examples with ajax functionality, not going well, thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$.get()` to load data from the server whenever the previous or back arrows are triggered.

[api.jquery.com/jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)